# Automatically implement/derive a trait for the boxed dyn of that trait

Tags: rust

I have a trait, `pub trait Entity {...}`, which is used to represent the core functionality of a system I'm writing. I also have a type,`pub struct OwnedEntity<E = Box<dyn Entity>> where E: Entity + 'static {...}`, which acts as a storage wrapper for this type - this is needed due to the side-effects of another system.

The users of `OwnedEntity` usually won't want to know the actual type of what's being stored, but some will. This is why I have the optional type parameter `E` which is a boxed entity by default, rather than just removing the type parameter entirely and storing it internally as a boxed entity.

Is it possible for me to implement `impl<E: Entity> Entity for Box<E>` similar to using a derive macro on the `trait Entity` declaration? This is needed since `Box` only implements deref, whereas I need it to specifically implement `Entity` for the `OwnedEntity` `where` clause, and I don't want to implement it by hand.

Comment: When you tried implementing it, what error did you get?

Comment: There's no errors, but there's a dozen methods that I don't want to replicate. This is mainly a convenience thing, like `#[derive(Clone)]`, and I was wondering if I could do something similar here.

Comment: No need to replicate, just forward them. There is no 'derive_boxed' macro that I know of.

Comment: I expected some delegation crate to exist for doing that, but found nothing that allows you to just annotate the trait.